# What is a good rifle in Fallout New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Currently I'm using the "AER14 Prototype" and while it hits quite hard I'm wondering if there's anything better?

I've also got the "All American" assault rifle but in single shot mode it feels quite weak. I've just picked up the "YCS/186" and while that seems to be very powerful I think the 1 shot, reload aspect will drive me mad.

Can anyone tell me a good rifle for me to carry around? It can be an energy weapon or a normal gun as I've got skill points in both.

Comment: Sorry Dan K. is right I didn't specify what I'm after, I'm more interested in damage per shot but with a reasonable rate of fire, perhaps. In Fallout 3 I liked using "Ol' Painless" if that helps clear things up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what you're looking for (most damage in one shot or highest DPS), but according to [this](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_weapons), the Light Machine Gun has the highest DPS of a regular rifle while the YCS/186 has the highest DPS of an energy rifle.

Answer (score 1):

AER14 w/ overcharged ammo and the Finesse perk is a good combo.  Overcharged ammo gives you good DT penetration and the Finesse perks gives you a much better chance for criticals.  YCS/186 has good DPS, but a very slow rate of fire.  All-american is a great all around weapon, (it's a unique version of the marksman carbine), high rate of fire, scoped for sniping and if you pair it with ap 5.56 you've got a weapon that can take on death claws fairly well.  (not as well as an anti-material rifle or ycs/186 to the head, but...)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Honest Hearts add-on, a good weapon to find is the [Survivalist's rifle](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/Survivalist's_rifle). It is 12.7mm rounds, magazine fed and semi automatic. Quick reload, high damage and DPS.

I use this rifle frequently and it repairs with a service rifle.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go stealthy, my regular weapon progression goes

**Rifles:** Varmint Rifle -> Ratslayer (unique Varm. Rifl.) -> Sniper Rifle -> Anti-Materiel Rifle

(*All fully modded. All weapons include silencers/suppressors*)